# Can't replicate attachment from couchDB to pouchDB

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, couchdb, pouchdb

For a few days I have a big problem with attachments in CouchDB/pouchDB

My app working perfectly on browser Chrome when I running "ionic Serve"

But when I running "ionic run android" my app doesn't work because I guess PouchDB Can't save to IndexedDb attachment from CouchDB (When I delete a document from CouchDB type attachment application works).

I suppose the problem is after update Chrome on mobile because versions of applications that worked, now not working.

On remote debugging in the console, I don't see any problem.

Has anybody a similar problem for a few days?

Ionic 3.2
Pouch 6.4
Adapter indexedDb or Cordova-SQL ( on both is the same problem)